# Integral with unknown constants

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am evaluating an integral with constants that are not specified, but I am not sure why it takes so long for it to give an output, so I just decided to cancel the running. The integral is given by,

$\int_0^1 dy \frac{ c a^3 y^2 }{ ((1 - b^3 y^3)(1 - c^2 a^4 y^4))^{1/2} }$

```
d = 2;
z = 10;
b = a/z;
SumConvergence[(c a^(d + 1)
     y^d)/((1 - b^(d + 1) y^(d + 1)) (1 - c^2 (a y)^(2 d)))^(1/2), y]
Integrate[(c a^(d + 1) y^
    d)/((1 - b^(d + 1) y^(d + 1)) (1 - c^2 (a y)^(2 d)))^(1/2), {y, 0,
   1}, Assumptions -> {c > 0, a > 0}]
```

d indicates dimensions so in this case I set for example, d=2, while a,b are constants (leave it open so I can put values later). In the end, I want to get an expression for "c" in terms of "a" (since "a" also gives "b") through evaluation of the integral.

UPDATE: I changed the integral expression a bit compared to my first post, now I tried doing the SumConvergence command and it returns a TRUE value so this new integral that I posted converges but I do not know why it does not return the condition of convergence. Also, the Integrate command still does not return anything even though the function converges.

Comment: You have a typo in that you have `ay` which should have a space between the two letters:  `a y`.  Also, you don't need to state `y>0`.  But after fixing those errors, *Mathematica* states that the integral does not converge on {0,1}.  But it does converge if you restrict `a<0`.

Comment: `d = 2;
z = 1;
b = a/z;
Integrate[(y^d (1 - (b y)^(d + 1))^1/2)/(1 - c^2 (a*y)^(2 d))^1/2, {y,
   0, 1}, Assumptions -> c > 0 && a > 0]` produces $$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{2 a^2 c+\log \left(\frac{2}{a^2 c+1}-1\right)-2 c^{3/2} \tan ^{-1}\left(a \sqrt{c}\right)+2 c^{3/2} \tanh ^{-1}\left(a \sqrt{c}\right)}{16 a^3 c^3},c<\frac{1}{a^2}\right] .$$

Comment: @user64494 I think the exponent 1/2 affects the result, I tried writing 0.5 instead of 1/2 and it does not return anything.

Comment: Your Mathematica code does not match your latex expression at all. Try evaluating `z^1/2` and then try `z^(1/2)` or `Sqrt[z]` and see the difference. Introducing decimal points is probably a very bad idea. Once you fix your exponent problem you can also try `Apart[..your fraction..]` which should get the square root out of the denominator, but even that doesn't seem to be enough. You just have a very complicated rational function with no easy integral.

Comment: @Bill Sorry, I fixed my code in the post although what I have actually running in my Mathematica is properly written. Bottomline is, it does not return anything for whatever conditions I put in the Assumptions.

Comment: @mathemania Cold you please clarify "In the end, I want to get an expression for "c" in terms of "a" (since "a" also gives "b") through evaluation of the integral" . Do you need a symbolic result?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, I need a symbolic result so that I can tune $a$ for a corresponding $c$.

Comment: *Hyperelliptic integrals* such as the one in the OP usually do not have a closed form that is known to *Mathematica*.

Comment: @mathemania The mysterical "tuning a[c]" can't be done numerically?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I was under the impression Mathematica might have a way to give a symbolic form, but if doing it numerically is the only way then do I need to impose anything?

Comment: @mathemania Suppose you could solve your integral numerically, let's name it `int[a,c,d]`. This expression could be used like a symbolical one! What would be your next step "tuning a[c]"?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann My goal is to find an expression linking $a$ to $c$, so maybe even numerically solving it is ok.

Comment: @mathemania Ok I'll show you how to get the numerical integral depending on `a,c` .

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Is there any way where I can put values on `int[a,c]` and `a` and give a result of `c`? The 3DPlot looks amazing but maybe there is an algorithmic way of obtaining `c` given `int[a,c]` and `a`.

Comment: @mathemania You could try `FindRoot[ value== int[value_a,c ],{c,...}]` (altenatively: `NSolve`, `Nminimize`). Perhaps you can give an examplary equation?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann So suppose I set `1=int[2,c]` where `a=2`, I want to find the corresponding `c`. 
Is it correct to write `FindRoot[1 == int[2, c], {c,1}]` ?
I have also tried `NSolve[0.5 == int[1, c], c]` but it says that the integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}.

Comment: @mathemania I modified my answer, now `FindRoot` works (no explanation why )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**modified**

It looks like there is only a numerical solution.
Try

```
int[a_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
Block[{d = 2, z = 10}, 
NIntegrate[(c a^(d + 1) y^d)/((1 - (a/z) ^(d + 1) y^(d + 1)) (1 - c^2 (a y)^(2 d)))^(1/2) , {y, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 5]]
```

`int[a,c]` might be used like a general Mathematica function.

```
Plot3D[int[a, c], {a, 0, 2}, {c, 0, 3}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "c", "int[a,c]"},PlotRange -> {0, 1}] // Quiet
```

[image]

Now it possibel to tune `a[c]`

```
FindRoot[ int[2, z] == 1 , {z, 0 }] // Quiet//Chop
(*{z -> 0.244368}*)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of "?NumericQ" in the int function? As I know it is just to ensure an object is a numeric quantity. Also what is the reason of putting "//Quiet" in the end of the plot? Is it supposed to display a warning?

Comment: The purpose of `_?Numerics` is to run  NIntegrate   only if `a,c` are numeric. `//Quiet`  fades out some messages of `NIntegrate`.